# Visualization Tableau - Remove an option from a filter

Tags: visualization, analytics, data-visualization, tableau-api

This is the link of my visualization: [My dashboard](http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/ro/NotaTotal?%3aembed=y&%3adisplay_count=no#1)

In the tab "Cursos por ciclo", I would like to know how to remove the option "PTJE.TOTAL" from the filter "CURSO".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new calculated field.

Right click on CURSO and select "create calculated field" then use this formula:

> IF left([CURSO], 4) <> "PTJE" THEN [CURSO] END

Basically, this means: if the value does not start with "PTJE" then include it.

Then use the new calculated field as a filter, you will see that it does not include the "PTJE. TOTAL" value (it has been replaced with nulls now). So when you apply a quick filter the "PTJE. TOTAL" value won't appear.

Note: Normally I'd use something simpler like:

> IF [CURSO] <> "PTJE. TOTAL" THEN [CURSO] END

but that is not working with your data for some reason.

Also, you can read more about calculated fields in Tableau here:
http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/i181523.html